# APS Core MVC 2 вернуться на на страницу с который был вызов

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Есть метод удаления элемента из справочника. Вызов этого метода может происходить с различных форм

```
<a asp-controller = "Q" asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id ="@item.Id">Delete Item</a>
```

Как после удаления вернуться на форму с которой был произведен вызов

Comment: Вы удаляете элементы гет запросом?

Comment: @tym32167 нет post запрос